# Obtener valores de un arreglo modificado dentro de un condicional

Tags: c

Llevo poco tiempo con el lenguaje C y me he quedado atascado con un tema de cambio de valores en un arreglo

El código es el siguiente:

```
int tipo[] = {0x01, 0x02};

if(a == 0) // a ya ha sido declarada en otra parte del código 
{
   tipo[1] = 0xFF;
  
}

printf("Tipo = %02X %02X", tipo[0], tipo[1]);
```

El resultado esperado es tipo = 0x01 0xFF, pero no es así, me devuelve  0x01 0x02

Evidentemente la variable a vale 0 al llegar al IF, por tanto entra en él

He leido varios post al respecto, pero no consigo dar con ello

Agradezco de antemano vuestra ayuda y consejos

Comment: Muestra todo el código si puede ser, he realizado eso mismo que tú y me sale correcto. Debe ser que a lo mejor a no valga 0 en alguna parte de tu programa.

Comment: Por el resultado que te sale evidentemente a!=0. Prueba asignado a=0 antes del if y seguro te saldrá el resultado que esperas y si a pesar de eso sigue igual entonces debes tener problema en la definición de la variable "a".  Ahora en "c" el 0 es igual a NULL cuando comparas con algunas variables por ejemplo punteros. Por lo tanto, basta que el puntero este definido para que no sea = 0;

Answer (score 1):

He descubierto donde tenía el error.

La variable a no en vale 0 en el momento de llegar al IF porque tenía el valor 1. El fallo ha sido en otra parte donde debía cambiar su valor a 0.